# Code Sorting Tool for .NET

Tags: .net

Are there any tools for sorting and organizing tools for C#/VB. Specifically one that does stuff like moving all the fields to the top of the file, alphabetizing the methods, etc.

Comment: Is there nothing in Resharper or Code Rush?

Comment: You guys should have posted those comments as answers.

Comment: Code Rush doesn't currently offer anything like that, but I think it is finally in their road map.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper has the ability to do this. If you go to `ReSharper -> Options -> Code Cleanup` you can enable the `Reorder type members` option. This enabled the code reordering when you do a code  cleanup (`ReSharper -> Tools -> Cleanup Code...`).

There is also an option to [set a custom template](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Reordering_Type_Members_C#_only) to specify how to rearrange the code. This can be set in `ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Type Members Layout`.

Comment: Note that such reordering, when combined with DVCS' like Mercurial or Git, will make merging difficult. It is much better for merging go leave code where you added it, than have a tool reorder your code. At least that's been my experience.

Comment: @Lasse: I agree. What I've seen recommended in the past is to reformat/reorder the code before you check it in each time, including before the *first* check-in. This ensures that the VCS diffs are kept to a minimum.